# PyMVPA installation error

Tags: python, installation

I tried install PyMVPA package using MacPorts:

```
sudo port install py27-pymvpa +scipy +nibabel +hcluster +libsvm
```

The terminal returns:

```
Error: org.macports.build for port py27-pymvpa returned: command execution failed
Error: Processing of port py27-pymvpa failed
```

Tried to set the path to:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Still has the building error.

Comment: As explained in the [MacPorts Guide](https://guide.macports.org/): Run `sudo port clean` then try again. Try adding the debug flag (`-d`). Look for errors in the debug output, and then figure out how to address them, or edit your question here to add the debug output if you need help.

Comment: @JoshKelley Thanks. I installed it directly from source.